Web Server returning wait page instead of the intended response for HttpClient request in VB.NET
So I have my webpage at: http://daera.net/dmoon/issuecmds.php
Since this is my own site, I can modify it in whatever manner I want. Right now it is meant to send a simple, static response with this single line:
<?php echo "Hello. This is a test to check the functioning of web based softwares"; ?>

This shows the expected one liner page whenever I open it in any web browser.
The problem arises when I try to reach my page using my VB.NET application. The said app simply reads the page and shows the result in a multi line textbox. This is the code I am using to read the webpage:
Async Function ReadPage() As Task(Of String)
    Dim res As String
    Using client As HttpClient = New HttpClient()
        Using response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.GetAsync(str_url)
            Using content As HttpContent = response.Content
                Dim result As String = Await content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                res = result
                If res.Length < 4 Then
                    res = "Err"
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    Return res
End Function

Private Async Sub btnRead_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRead.Click
    Randomize()
    Dim rnd As New Random
    Dim rand As Integer = rnd.Next()
    str_url = "http://daera.net/dmoon/issuecmds.php?&rand=" + rand.ToString()
    txtResult.Text = Await ReadPage()
End Sub

Note that I am using a random number in the address to avoid getting a cached response. The code runs fine, but the problem is that sometimes (just randomly), sometimes this would show the code for a "Please Wait" page instead of the simple one liner response intended in the php code mentioned above.
Edit: After getting no "Please Wait..." page for more than 2 weeks, I was finally able to see it again. I copied all the response/HTML obtained by the ReadPage() function. Here it is:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <title>One moment, please...</title>
    <style>
    body {
        background: #F6F7F8;
        color: #303131;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        margin-top: 45vh;
        text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <h1>Please wait while your request is being verified...</h1>
    <form id="wsidchk-form" style="display:none;" action="/z0f76a1d14fd21a8fb5fd0d03e0fdc3d3cedae52f" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" id="wsidchk" name="wsidchk"/>
    </form>
    <script>
    (function(){
        var west=+((+!+[]+!![]+!![])+(+!+[]+[])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!+[]+!![]+[])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])),
            east=+((+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!+[]+[])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+!+[])),
            x=function(){try{return !!window.addEventListener;}catch(e){return !!0;} },
            y=function(y,z){x() ? document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',y,z) : document.attachEvent('onreadystatechange',y);};
        y(function(){
            document.getElementById('wsidchk').value = west + east;
            document.getElementById('wsidchk-form').submit();
        }, false);
    })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>


I understand that this issue is occurring from the site host server and not the VB.NET code.
Is it some sort of auto defense mechanism against bots/spiders etc? Where can I disable this in the site settings. Here is (probably) the relevant section of site settings:


When I suggested to take the code from here, I meant all of it -- Remove that Randomize() thing, it has nothing to do with the Random class (which should be declared as a static (Shared) object, or you could use its static methods when targeting .NET 6+)

@Jimi OK, but that still doesn't help with the "Please Wait" response I sometimes get from the server ...

Well, I've tested it, just repeatedly clicking a Button as you're doing here, and in a loop (adding await Task.Delay(100) between calls). The response was never the one you're reporting, which is not a standard response, BTW, it looks more like a HTML page with an embedded refresh of some sort. I can't say, I've never gotten it

@Jimi I just got the Please Wait... page. I have posted all the HTML of the page in my edit. When I viewed this page in a browser tonight, the Please Wait... page appeared for merely 1 second or so and then automatically updated the contents to show the one liner response needed from it.
